# Does WCF BasicHttpBinding support generic lists?

Tags: wcf, generic-list, basichttpbinding

I am trying to add a new service method to my existing WCF web service project which uses BasicHttpBinding. 
My new service method accepts a class as a parameter and this class has a `List<T>` variable. After adding this method, my web service client can not add the service reference. It receives  `(415) Unsupported Media Type.` error message. 
Does that mean WCF BasicHttpBinding does not support List type? Should I use array type instead? If it supports List, then where should I look for the error?

Comment: Did you try to check for this http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.fr/2010/06/fixing-wcf-remote-server-returned-error.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List` is supported.

**Check the configuration on misspelling!**

For example, NetworkingService instead of NetwokingService [link](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2010/06/fixing-wcf-remote-server-returned-error.html).

When you adding the service reference check configuration window. There is a choice how to consider `List, Dictionary, Array` when data is send.
Choose as `List`.

Do not try work with anonymous generic `List<T>`. WCF cannot create WSDL information for anonymous types. It may be `List<MyClass>`.

Also it is not recommended for using because of data ceiling. The maximum bytes value is configurable but is limited.
The better solution is to implement new class

```
public class MyClassContainer
{
    public Guid Id;
    public List<MyClass> Items;
}
```

And then send or receive objects by parts (by 10, 100 ,...).

Comment: it didnt help. the problem still exists.

Comment: do you have concrete class like List<MyClass>?

Comment: Try to open wsdl page for your service enpoint. Does it work?

Comment: Thanks, my problem sides in an other place. i realised that i had not insert [DataContract] header on my abstract class which i use in the List.